# custom notification use programmatically generated drawables

Tags: android

I was trying to implement custom notifications in android.

Basically, i have a music player application and i am trying to set a custom notification for the app.

app:minimum:16&maximum:26;

```
    RemoteViews contentView=new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.custom_notification);
    Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(songImage);
    Drawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bm);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notificationIcon,drawable);
```

This is what i did, for every image i want the icon to replaced by its album art.

Everything is fine until the last line in the above code.

`setImageViewResource` takes two arguments  first one being the element id and the second being the drawable id.

But the problem is that , i am generating drawables depending on the song which has to drawn programmatically.

How can i use this method or set the album art for the corresponding image view?

**Custom Notification.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/playicon"
        android:id="@+id/notificationIcon"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#000"

            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/notificationPrev"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/notificationPlay"
        android:background="@drawable/smallpause"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/notificationForw"
        android:background="@drawable/forw"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using setImageViewResource() you can use setImageViewBitmap() here you can load which ever bitmap you want.